# Find specific attribute and get its value

Tags: jquery, find, attr

I have this:

```
<button>Click</button>
<p class="intro" voice="next,1">My name is Donald.</p>
```

and need to find the "voice" attribute and fetch its value "next" 
I tried this by looking all the question but it shows undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
    var ab = $(document).find("[voice=' ']")[0];
    console.log(ab);
    });
});
```

Comment: It works in my case if i write var ab = $("p").attr("voice")[0]; so don't worry about validation.

Comment: you can use `$(document).find(".intro").attr("voice")`

Comment: can't use any other tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[voice]` selector to select your element and `attr()` method to get attribute value. After that use `split()` method to get your value. like following.

```js
 $("button").click(function() {
    var ab = $("[voice]"),
        text = ab.attr('voice').split(',')[0];
    console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<p class="intro" voice="next,1">My name is Donald.</p>
```

Comment: Need only "next" value, with your example when i do this console.log(ab.attr('voice')[0]); it gives me "n" only

Comment: ya my fault i didn't apply split()

Comment: What should i do in case if i have multiple voice tags like: voice="next,1" voice="play,1" voice="previous,1" mu current code only searches for first voice tag.

Comment: You should use `each`. See https://jsfiddle.net/exc88sad/ @naveendharni

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").on('click', function() {
    var ab = $(document).find("[voice]").attr('voice');
    console.log(ab);
    });
});
```

play here if you want https://jsfiddle.net/up9ub1uh/

and it's better to use `data-voice` instead just `voice` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
    var ab = $("p").attr('voice');
    console.log(ab);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<p class="intro" voice="next,1">My name is Donald.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var ab = $(".intro").attr('voice');
    var new1 = ab.split(",");
    console.log(new1[0]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<p class="intro" voice="next,1">My name is Donald.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the .find as you can see in this example:

```
<p>Once there was a <em title="huge, gigantic">large</em> dinosaur...</p
 <script>
 var title = $( "em" ).attr( "title" );
 console.log(title);
 </script>
```

You should only do this:

```
<p class="intro" voice="next,1">My name is Donald.</p>
 <script>
 var title = $( "p" ).attr( "voice" );
 console.log(title);
  </script>
```